mpi4py appears to be installed by virtual environment, yet not recognized when imported?
I would like to use mpi4py within my virtual environment, so, I installed it using conda install mpi4py.  This seems to have worked successfully as indicated by the following output:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 

Solving environment: done.... 

 # All requested packages already installed. 


However I then try to import it in python3, and of course I get the following:

>>> import mpi4py                                                                                                                                                                                

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                 

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                      

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpi4py'          


What makes conda believe that this package is installed and how do I connect it with python3?
